# Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am really struggling with this integral that needs to be evaluated. I am really struggling with factoring the denominator in order to find the roots or poles. This is the main thing I am struggling with, nothing conceptually really. I have posted both the question and a screenshot of all of my work. If anybody could show me how to factor the denominator to get the poles/show me where I am going wrong in my work, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: it seems you have removed the integral from the question in your last edit, but it is required to understand the question itself (even if it has already been answered, other people would find this question interesting for similar problems, so it is better to keep the question readable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you eventually want to factorise the denominator, then it's not a good idea to expand out the square at the start.

For $z=e^{i\theta}$
$$2-\sin\theta=\frac{4i-z+z^{-1}}{2i}=-\frac{z^2-4iz-1}{2iz}.$$
We can factorize the numerator by completing the square
$$z^2-4iz-1=(z-2i)^2+3=(z-2i-\sqrt3 i)(z-2i+\sqrt3 i)$$
so that
$$2-\sin\theta=-\frac{(z-2i-\sqrt3 i)(z-2i+\sqrt3 i)}{2iz}.$$
Now put this into your integral.

Comment: The poles will be where the denominator vanishes. Because of the squaring these poles will be double poles: twice the fun!